# css table row not going up to width of table

Tags: css, html-table, row, bootstrap-4

I have a table that is set to `overflow-y: auto` and `display:block` but the problem is the rows do not take up space until the full width of the table.
Below is a screenshot:
[image: Table rows]

Here is the code:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <table class="table table-hover ">
                <thead>
                    <tr><th style="text-align: center">Excel List</th></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Excel" ng-keyup="searchExcel()" ng-model="excelSearchTerm">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="tbody-style excel-list-table">
                    <tr ng-repeat="excel in excelList" ng-if="excelSearchTerm == ''">
                        <td ng-click="ctrlClickExcel($event, excel)" ng-class="{'selected' : excel.selected}">{{excel.dir}}</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr ng-repeat="excel in excelSearchResults" ng-if="excelSearchTerm != ''">
                        <td ng-click="ctrlClickExcel($event, excel)" ng-class="{'selected' : excel.selected}">{{excel.dir}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
</div>
```

[image: Style]

If I remove `display: block` then that's the only time the rows take up the full width but it won't overflow anymore and will take up the fullscreen instead of the height of 250px.

I'm using Bootstrap.

EDIT: 
I managed to have a workaround. I just added another table for the heading and another table that is contained in a div with overflow-y and display block.

Comment: remove `display: block`... why do you need that?

Comment: can you provide working snippet code...?

Comment: @kukkuz If I remove that, overflow-y won't work anymore with the height of 250px.

Comment: I managed to have a workaround. I just added another table for the heading and another table that is contained in a div with overflow-y and display block.

Answer (score 1):

Add a DIV outside the table and then put overflow

```
<div style="overflow-y: auto;display:block;height:250px">
<table width="100%">
..
```

Comment: It works but I need "Excel List" and the search bar to stay on top.

Comment: I managed to have a workaround. I just added another table for the heading and another table that is contained in a div with overflow-y and display block.

Answer (score 0):

Change **class="col-md-6"** to **class="col-md-12"** your code

Comment: The width just changed but the rows are still the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can [fix the table header](https://codepen.io/tjvantoll/pen/JEKIu), or simply you can simply move the search bar and the title out,

```
Excel List<br>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Excel" ng-keyup="searchExcel()" ng-model="excelSearchTerm">
<div style="overflow-y: auto;display:block;height:250px">
<table width="100%">
```